# ajax Miltipart FormData - upload Data and Files in one Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, multipartform-data

I would like to upload both files(images and PDF files) and data(select box values and input fields) with one ajax call. Ive got to the stage where i can successfully upload the two files i need but i am having great difficulty appending the values within the input and select tags to the FormData object.

Been stuck on this for ages now so any help will be much appreciated.

Below is the ajax call its self - if this is not enough and you need more info then let me know.

```
$(function(){

$("#ajaxComm").submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

imageInput = document.getElementById("File-0")
pdfInput = document.getElementById("File-1")

imageFile = imageInput.files[0];
pdfFile = pdfInput.files[0];

var formdata = new FormData();  


formdata.append('file-0[]', imageFile);
formdata.append('file-1[]', pdfFile);

   $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
    }

  }); 
 });

});
```

Thanks 
kemil

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: what have you tried? I would think that formdata.append('field1', document.getElementById("field1").value); would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an ajax call, you could use `GET` method to append select box and input field data (if they fit into the url size), it does not need to be a pretty url; and use `POST` for the files, as that part is already working.